# distinct objects between two arrays based on a property - lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

Is there a direct method to get distinct objects **into a new array based on object's property** from two different arrays ?

Currently looping through first array and then comparing with each object in second array to maintain a counter and push into new array, when distinct.

```
   var newArray = [];
   _.each(firstArray, function(item) {               //loop items in 1st []
      var count = 0;        
     _.each(secondArray, function(secondItem) {
       if(secondItem.property = item.property) {      
        count++
       }
     }  
  if(count == 0)   newArray.push(item); //push distinct item into new []
  }
```

example Data :

```
var array1 = [{id:1, busNum: "1234"}, {id:2, busNum:"4567"}]
var array2 = [{id:1, busNum: "2344"}, {id:2, busNum:"1234"}]
```

want to eliminate common buses (ones with same bus number)

```
  var newArray = [{id:2, bus:"4567"}, {id:1, bus:"2344"]
```

Comment: and some/an example(s) of what is inputted, and outputted

Comment: It would be great if you create a plunker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`_.xorBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#xorBy) for a [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

```js
var array1 = [{id:1, busNum: "1234"}, {id:2, busNum:"4567"}],
    array2 = [{id:1, busNum: "2344"}, {id:2, busNum:"1234"}],
    result = _.xorBy(array1, array2, 'busNum');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is `_.xorBy`.  Xor (exclusive or), will give you only elements that are in either set, but not both.  For example:

`_.xorBy(array1, array2, 'bus')`

You can read the docs for it [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#xorBy).

Comment: Just a caveat, this will ***not*** include distinct element, rather list all elements that exist in ***both*** arrays.

Comment: oops, sorry, that's not what you want... one second

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a outer join, in terms of set mathematics. The corresponding function is: [***`_.xorBy`***](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#xorBy)

#### Example:

```
_.xorBy(array1, array2, 'prop')
```

---

You can also use: [***`_.hashFullOuterJoin`***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-joins), like:

```
_.hashFullOuterJoin(array1, 'prop', array2, 'prop')
```